# Dynamic Filter for Report

Tags: reporting

I have designed a report with one filter say User.Division = 'XYZ'.
I have create a custom link which I am using to pass this parameter as pv0 and launching the report via the link.
For example, my link is ?pv0='DivA'
So my report goes like All accounts where User.Division = 'DivA';

When I access the report with Admin profile,the parameter is getting applied to the filter properly.
However, when I try the same process with a different profile (but having similar access as the admin on reports), the parameter is not getting applied to the filter

I have no idea where I am going wrong. Please help.

Thanks,

Comment: did you check if the other profile has similar access to the object and fields used in the report & its filters ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I actually found a work around, now I have created a formula in my object, which evaluates the criteria I wanted in the report, and based on the return of the formula I am generating the report.

Thanks,